# cambio de posiciones de elementos

Tags: css, css3

como puedo cambiar el orden de posiciones de las cajas  1 y 2, que primero aparesca la caja 2 y luego la 1 y lo mismo con las cajas 3 y 4, que aparesca primero la caja 4 y luego la 3, quedando en este orden:  "2, 1, 4, 3"  en este link se puede visualizar el codigo

https://codepen.io/tommy-solano-pe-afiel/pen/KOQRaX?editors=1100

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

div>p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <p>caja 1</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <p>caja 2</p>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <p>caja 3</p>
</div>
<div class="box4">
  <p>caja 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Distribuirlas de otra manera? ¿Cambiar el orden? Estaría bien saber que cosas has intentado y no han funcionado

Comment: quisiera que el orden de las cajas cambie, que primero aparesca la caja 2 y luego la caja 1 y lo mismo con las cajas 3 y 4, que primero aparesca la 4 y luego la 3, utilize "translate" pero aqui yo debo manejarme con pixeles y si la pagina es abierta desde dispositivos con diferente tamaño de pantalla el resultado sera distinto, quisiera saber si hay otra forma de poder cambiar las posiciones de las cajas o si "translate" es la unica forma y como lo podria aplicar de una manera adecuada, gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el modelo de layout `flex` el cual te permite acomodar el flujo de los elementos a tu gusto usando su propiedad `order`. Eso sí debes tener en cuenta es que este cambio de posiciones en los elementos es solo visual, es decir no modifica el DOM.

Para usar `flex` es necesario tener un contenedor que será el **elemento padre** y los items que serán los **elementos hijos** es indispensable tener esta estructura porque `flex` dispone de propiedades exclusivas para elementos `padre e hijo`.

1° En tu HTML debes agregar un contenedor al que llamaré `container`

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1"><p>caja 1</p></div>
    <div class="box2"><p>caja 2</p></div>
    <div class="box3"><p>caja 3</p></div>
    <div class="box4"><p>caja 4</p></div>
  </div>
```

2° Mejorar el CSS y ser más específicos al momento de darle estilos a las cajas, para ello uso un selector de clase.

**CSS**

```
[class^="box"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Luego aplicamos un `display: flex` al `container` con la finalidad de volver la caja flexible y poder hacer uso de `order` el cual es una propiedad que solo aplica a los elementos hijos.

Usamos esta propiedad para cambiar el orden en que se muestran los elementos, el valor por defecto es `order: 0` es decir tus cajas se posicionan en el mismo orden que tu HTML. Para conseguir lo que mencionas solo debes cambiar el valor de `order` en cada una de cajas obteniendo así el resultado deseado.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  order: 2;
}
.box2 {
  order: 1;
}
.box3 {
  order: 4;
}
.box4 {
  order: 3;
}
```

Puedes ver el resultado funcionando [aquí el enlace](https://codepen.io/Mercyles/pen/MNVKrV?editors=1100).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer cambios con animaciones, te dejo un ejemplo de cambio de color en la caja 1 y de cambio de posición en la caja 2.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px 50px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box1{
-webkit-animation:change-color 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
-moz-animation:change-color 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
-ms-animation:change-color 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
animation:change-color 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
0%{ background-color:green; }
100%{ background-color:red; }
}

@keyframes change-color {
0%{ background-color:green; }
100%{ background-color:red; }
}

.box2{
-webkit-animation:change-position 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
-moz-animation:change-position 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
-ms-animation:change-position 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
animation:change-position 4s ease 0s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes change-position {
0%{ margin-left:0;}
100%{ margin-left:50%; }
}

@keyframes change-position {
0%{ margin-left:0; }
100%{ margin-left:50%; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-transition.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="transition2.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"><p>caja 1</p></div>
    <div class="box box2"><p>caja 2</p></div>
    <div class="box box3"><p>caja 3</p></div>
    <div class="box box4"><p>caja 4</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```